# select certain "column" for JDO entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a entity in the appengine datastore called DataBase which contains some attributes or columns or what ever it is named in JDO,I want to select only some columns from that entity so i use select statment like that

```
 String query = "select from " + DataBase.class.getName()+" where id == '"+user+"'";
List<DataBase> greetings = (List<DataBase>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

so i select all things in that entity its id=user...fine.I actually want to get certain column from that list and put it in a separate list so i can do some functionality on it can somebody help???

Answer (score 2):

You can't select individual columns in App Engine. Entities are stored as serialized protocol buffers, so they're retrieved as a unit, not individually.

Comment: ok...but after i select the whole entity is there a way to get individual columns from that list. For example List.getaddress...in which getaddress is column in the entity ??

Comment: @Islam I'm not sure I understand the problem - you get back a list of entities. The properties you want are on the individual entities returned by the query.

Comment: sorry if I'm some what misleading.I'll explain further hoping you figure my problem.I had an entity class called DataBase which contains fields(columns) index,user, location,and some other fields I select form Database where user=logged in user, then I put the result of selected query in List<Database> R .Here is the problem that i want to get only the index and do some functionality on them also take location and do some functionality on them really i want to get their average.so my question is if there is a way i can get those fields from the List<DataBase> R taht contain the returned query?

Comment: Standard JDOQL is "SELECT AVG(field) FROM MyClass". Whether GAE/J supports it is unknown to me

Comment: @Islam You need to retrieve each of the entities from the list and sum up their value yourself.